# React router showing white blank page

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand why I am getting blank page even after changing Switch to Router, can anyone help to fix?
App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'
import Form from './Components/Form';
import Person from './Components/Person'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Headers from './Components/Header';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
    <div>
      <Headers></Headers>
        Welcome to home
  
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/form" element={<Form />}>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/person" element={<Person />}>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        </Route>
        </Routes>

    </div >

    </Router>
  )
}
export default App;
```

When I checked console log:

> Uncaught Error: You cannot render a  inside another .
> You should never have more than one in your app.

Comment: it looks like you already wrap your `App` component by `Router`, could you check where you use `App` component?

Comment: Thanks it was because `  <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        </Route>` I removed it and worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nesting the router as you're rendering `<Route path="/" element={<App />}>`. That's why you're getting the error.

I suggest you create another component (e.g. Home) to render for the root path. Take a look at the [documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing).

Comment: Your answer saved my life literally. I read literally all the answers on this issue on Stackoverflow, what I noticed is that the reason this error happens is not the same all the time. But the moment I commented out the above i.e.,  {/* <Route path="/" element={<App />}/>  */}, I eliminated the error. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I'm having a similar problem: